# "Better" vs "better off"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *better* and *better off*? For example:

> 1. You would be better if you accepted the job.
> 2. You would be better off if you accepted the job.

To me they sound alike. Could anyone tell me the difference please?

Comment: I think if there's no preposition at all, *You would be better if X* only works when ***better = in improved health*** (as in *You would be better by now if you had taken your medication*). In BrE (not sure about AmE) the more general sense of ***in improved circumstances*** can also be expressed as [*You would **do better to**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22You+would+do+better+to%22) [get a different job, etc.]*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[better](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/better) (adj)**

> of a higher standard, or more suitable, pleasing, or effective than other things or people

So the first sentence could mean:

*You would be more effective than others if you accepted the job.*

**[better off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/better-off)**

> in a more satisfactory situation than you were before
>
> Better off also means having more money and a better level of comfort in your life than you had before, or than someone else has

The second sentence means:

*You would have more money than before if you accepted the job.*